# How to use nazrin gem to call AWS CloudSearch expr method?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, full-text-search, geo

From here we can know that use `expr` function can get special data:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-locations.html

Use ruby `nazrin` gem also found the `expr` method:

https://github.com/tsuwatch/nazrin/blob/master/lib/nazrin/search_client.rb#L108

But when tried to get special data as:

```
def get_data
  City.search.expr("distance=haversin(#{params[:latitude], #{params[:longitude]}, 'latitude', 'longitude'})").start(0).query(params[:keyword]).execute
end
```

Got error:

```
Invalid syntax in 'expr' parameter: Unexpected character ('d' (code 100)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [column: 2]
```

How to use it?